# htaccess rule for 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess

what is the `.htaccess` rule to 301 redirect:-

- `http://example.com/folder1/yourfile?blogid=91` to `http://example.com/folder1/abc1`
- `http://example.com/folder1/yourfile?blogid=92` to `http://example.com/folder1/abc2`

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the query string, you'll need to use mod_rewrite (as opposed to a simple mod_alias `Redirect`).

For example, to 301 redirect `/folder1/yourfile?blogid=91` to `/folder1/abc1` you could do the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^blogid=91$
RewriteRule ^folder1/yourfile$ /folder1/abc1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag (Apache 2.4+) is required to remove the query string from the redirected URL. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then your will need to add a trailing `?` to the *substitution* string instead, ie. `/folder1/abc1?`

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: thanks for your reply but it shows page not found and url form as http://example.com/folder1/abc?blogid=91

Comment: Sorry, you need to added the QSD flag (Apache 2.4+) to remove the query string from the target URL. I've updated my answer. Regarding the page-not-found error, does `/folder1/abc1` work OK when you request it directly?

Comment: Now my url formation is right http://www.example.com/folder1/abc , abc is my seo purpose title,  I want to just rewrite the url like above but there is no such page as abc.php is it possible?

Comment: Ah, that's a very different task than what you asked in your initial question - and requires a different solution. Have you already changed the URLs in your application to the "user-friendly" URL of the form `/folder1/abc`?

Comment: There is only one file, the content changes as per the blogid and every blog has a title which i want to show at the place of abc so I can not change urls in my application

Comment: I think you are mixing up "URL-path" and "filesystem-path". You can't change the "filesystem-path", but you can change the "URL-path" - which is what I think you are asking here. It is the URL-path that you need to change in your application. eg. Change the anchors on your page to `<a href="/folder1/abc1">foo</a>` - you then use `.htaccess` to internally rewrite the "URL-path" back to the underlying "filesystem-path" ie. `/folder1/yourfile?blogid=91`. (However, unless you _hardcode_ these rewrites ony by one, how do you map `abc1` to `91`?)